# Best way to write a concatenating PHP MS SQL Query and put it into a loop

Tags: php

So normally I would write queries and loops like follows:

```
    $result = mssql_query("SELECT Element FROM Table WHERE Type='Type'");

                while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { 
}
```

I know it isn't best practice but I am still learning and it works.

I used to concatenate my queries as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT Element ";
$query .= "FROM Table ";
$query .= "WHERE Condition = 'no' ";

$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
```

This isn't very secure however I have written a SQL Encode but I digress. I now face the problem of having t write a very long query and loop it. I have written the following, however it doesn't work. Can someone tell me if my syntax is correct, so that I can debug if the problem lays with my syntax or another element. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO Items (BasketID, Qty, ProductType, Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6, Element7, Element8, Element9, Element10, Element11, Element12, Element13, Element14, Element15, Element16, Element17, Element18, Element19, Element20, DateAdded, Notes)";
$query .= " VALUES ("$_SESSION['basketid']", "1", "Type1", "SQLencode($_POST['Element1'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element2'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element3'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element4'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element5'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element6'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element7'])",";
$query .= ""SQLencode($_POST['Element8'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element9'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element10'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element11']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element12']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element13']","SQLencode($_POST['Element14']","SQLencode($_POST['Element15']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element16']",";
$query .= ""SQLencode($_POST['Element17'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element18'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element19'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element20'])", "NOW()", "SQLencode($_POST['Notes'])" ) "

$insertsql = mssql_query($query);

while ($insertrow = mssql_fetch_array($insertsql)) { 


?>
```

I think/hope I am the right track, but I think my syntax for the actual query is slightly wrong somewhere but I can't quite figure out why, I keep getting unexpected t_variables. Can anyone point me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO Items (BasketID, Qty, ProductType, Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5, Element6, Element7, Element8, Element9, Element10, Element11, Element12, Element13, Element14, Element15, Element16, Element17, Element18, Element19, Element20, DateAdded, Notes)"; 
$query .= " VALUES ('$_SESSION['basketid']', '1', 'Type1', "SQLencode($_POST['Element1'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element2'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element3'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element4'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element5'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element6'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element7'])""; 
$query .= ""SQLencode($_POST['Element8'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element9'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element10'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element11']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element12']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element13']","SQLencode($_POST['Element14']","SQLencode($_POST['Element15']", "SQLencode($_POST['Element16']","; 
$query .= ""SQLencode($_POST['Element17'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element18'])","SQLencode($_POST['Element19'])", "SQLencode($_POST['Element20'])", "NOW()", "SQLencode($_POST['Notes'])" ) "
```

End of line 2 you are missing a comma

Comment: Thank you have corrected it :) but other than that my use of variables and such within the statement looks ok?

Comment: Should be - if it errors, there maybe some missing other characters still  but I didnt spot them off hand.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to do in an array:

```
$fields = array(
    'BasketId'    => $_SESSION['basketid'],
    'Qty'         => 1,
    'ProductType' => 'Type1',
    'Element1'    => SQLencode($_POST['Element1']),
    ...
);

$query = 'INSERT INTO Items ('
$query .= implode(',', array_keys($fields));
$query .= ') VALUES (';
foreach($fields as $value)
    $query .= is_numeric($value) ? $value : "'$value'";
$query .= ');';
```

You could also cook a sort of special syntax for your fields:

```
'Element1'     => '@Element1',
```

and then use `array_map` to convert all @-elements to SQLEncodes. This way you can't forget encoding an externally supplied values: if you forget the @, you enter an innocuous string.